# Vue.js 2 and Asp.Net MVC, how to enable auto reload on any *.ts, *.scss and *.vue file change?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, vue.js, iis-express

My local is running  on IIS Express from Visual Studio Debugger, I make change to any server side c# code on Visual Studio 2017 however any client side code I use VSCode to modify.

So I have VS2017 open and on debug mode, hosting my local with a self signed certificate on https://localhost:44300/ and for any *.ts, *.scss or *.vue code change I have VSCode open.

When I only develop just client side code without full-stack server code backing it up I can use live-server to watch for changes and it auto reloads the localhost site running on 8080.

I want to have auto reload on any file change while the local is running from VS2017 debugger.

How to do that?